# How to bind the index of an element in a listview in the ItemsSource of a second listview inside the first one?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my `QuestionsPage` I have a `ListView` (`AnswersListView`) inside another listview (`QuestionsListView`).
How can I make a reference of the index of the question (which is in QuestionsListView) in the `ItemsSource` of the `AnswersListView` ?
To try to make a it clearer, here is a simplified code... I would like to replace the `???` by the index of the question.
Hope it is understandable.

In my XAML :

```
<ListView x:Name="QuestionsListView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Challenge.questions}"
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <ListView x:Name="AnswersListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Challenge.questions[???].answers, Source={x:Reference QuestionsPage}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <local:AnswerButton Text="{Binding isCorrect}" Command="{Binding BindingContext.CheckAnswerCommand, Source={x:Reference QuestionsPage}" CommandParameter="{Binding isCorrect}"/>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And my models (to understand how one is related to the other):

```
public class ChallengeModel {   
    public int challengeId { get; set; }    
    public string challengeName { get; set; }   
    public ObservableCollection<Question> questions { get; set; }

    public ChallengeModel() { }
}

public class Question {     
    public string questionText { get; set; }    
    public ObservableCollection<Answer> answers { get; set; }

    public Question() { } 
}

public class Answer {   
    public bool isCorrect { get; set; }     
    public string answerText { get; set; }

    public Answer() { }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to reference it from the original `DataContext`. Using `ItemsSource` you are essentially setting the `Challenge.question` property as the data source for the list. Now when you define a `ListView.ItemTemplate`, you are actually in the context of one single question from the list. so every `{Binding}` inside the `DataTemplate` is relative to the question itself (unless you specify otherwise).

This means, you can just use `{Binding answers}` to bind the inner list to the list of available answers:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="QuestionsListView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Challenge.questions}"
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>    
            <ListView x:Name="AnswersListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding answers}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <local:AnswerButton Text="{Binding isCorrect}" Command="{Binding BindingContext.CheckAnswerCommand, Source={x:Reference QuestionsPage}" CommandParameter="{Binding isCorrect}"/>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Why make it simple when we can make it complicated?! Thanks Martin ;)